# Tasker - If at least one context is true

Tags: tasker

How do I make it run the tasks when at least one context is met?

For example, when either the phone cell or GPS context is met, it activates...and only runs the exit task when both are not met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell you can't create a profile that will trigger when 1 of 2 conditions are met. To achieve what you are looking for tasker would have you create 2 separate profiles that choose the same task to active when the condition is met. If this doesn't answer you question dead on please provide more details since the example seems to imply you have another question.